# .htaccess - not routing to public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I seem to be having a problem with my laravel installation, I am trying to make the url route to the public folder when you type domainname.com/laravel instead of showing the directory.

However when I put

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

into the .htaccess within the laravel directory; it just comes up with this.
[image]

Please tell me how I can fix this.. because I really do not know.

Comment: can you show some `routes` you have defined and also make sure you have placed `htaccess` in laravel root directory

Comment: It is a clean install, there are no new routes defined, and I have placed the .htaccess in the right place; it is in the laravel root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is host Laravel in a subdirectory of your website. Most of the time, Laravel apps are hosted in the root directory of the website, i.e. `yourdomain.com`. However, you want your Laravel app to show up in `yourdomain.com/laravel`. Correct? First, a warning:

> **This is NOT the recommended way to host a Laravel app**

However, if you really want to move things into a subdirectory, here's one way you can start.

#### Create subdirectory within `public/` and move core Laravel files there

By default, a clean Laravel install has the following files in the `public/` folder:

```
public/
  - .htaccess
  - favicon.ico
  - index.php
  - robots.txt
  - web.config
```

Create a subdirectory and move these files into it, e.g. if your subdirectory was called `laravel/` then your new structure would look like:

```
public/
  - laravel/
    - .htaccess
    - favicon.ico
    - index.php
    - robots.txt
    - web.config
```

It is important that you do NOT change the contents of the `.htaccess` file that comes with Laravel. Otherwise your site definitely won't work.

#### Update `index.php` so it can still find the Laravel core

Inside `public/laravel/index.php` you'll need to update all of the lines that look like:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

to look like:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

There should be two lines that need to be changed.

At this point, if someone were to visit `yourdomain.com/laravel` they would see the Laravel welcome screen. You will also be able to create routes the way you normally would within `app/Http/routes.php`. For example, if your routes file looked like:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/hiya', function() {
    return 'hiya!';
});
```

Then someone who visits `yourdomain.com/laravel/hiya` would see the word "hiya" on the screen.

### This may cause you LOTS of problems

Like has been said, Laravel is not typically meant to be run from a subdirectory, so using it in the way that I have described may cause lots of problems and unexpected behaviors.

However, you will still be able to host static files in your `public/` folder and serve them the way you would any website.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation; I just installed it into the root; so I placed all of the inner files within "laravel", into the "www" directory. This has worked, I tested it out on my local server i.e. xampp and it worked perfectly so I tried it on the actual server, although it does redirect you to the public directory.. it just displays a 500 Server error page, any advice?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "root". Wherever you created your website on your hard drive, Apache should be configured so that the `DocumentRoot` is pointed at the `public/` folder in your Laravel project. Making it work entirely depends upon keeping all of the Laravel files in the same place that they are relative to each other. In my explanation, I showed you how to move the files in the `public/` folder to a subfolder, but as I explained, this is very much non-standard and not recommended. I guess it's not clear to me what your goal is in restructuring Laravel the way that you are.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually not a recommended way to place your laravel files when you are placing you `project` in a subdirectory, There is a recommended steps to correctly placing the contents of the `directory`. First, leave the `.htaccess` as it was at the time of installation. Then here are few `steps` you can take to make your site work.

```
1. You see `public` directory, copy all the contents of the it and `paste` it in your `root` directory and then remove the `public` folder from the original place.
2.  then you make a single folder and put all the contents inside newly created folder except the contents of public folder that you just pasted in your root
```

a structure you will have after this in your root will be like

```
a) contents of public folder
b) a single folder, lets say  `myproject` including all the contents except public
```

now, you should edit `index.php` like

```
require __DIR__.'/myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/myproject/bootstrap/app.php';
```

here `myproject` is your folder name where you put all the contents except `public` directory contents

Finally, clear all the `cache` and your program should work
If you still want `.htaccess` to your work, i suggest you to do some search in forums